use cpp std::stacktrace raise err "stacktrace’ was not declared in this scope"
following is my code
// C++ program to illustrate the use of stacktrace 
#include <iostream>
#include <stacktrace>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// dummy function 
void foo() {
    // creating and initializing stacktrace object 
    stacktrace st = stacktrace::current();

    // printing stacktrace 
    cout << to_string(st);
}

// driver code 
int main() {
    foo();

    return 0;
}

I use following cli build cpp
    /tmp $ g++-13 -std=c++23 -o t /home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp_lib/draft/draft/test_out_backtrace.cpp -lstdc++_libbacktrace
/home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp_lib/draft/draft/test_out_backtrace.cpp: In function ‘void foo()’:
/home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp_lib/draft/draft/test_out_backtrace.cpp:11:5: error: ‘stacktrace’ was not declared in this scope
   11 |     stacktrace st = stacktrace::current();
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~
/home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp_lib/draft/draft/test_out_backtrace.cpp:4:1: note: ‘std::stacktrace’ is defined in header ‘<stacktrace>’; did you forget to ‘#include <stacktrace>’?
    3 | #include <stacktrace>
  +++ |+#include <stacktrace>
    4 | #include <string>
/home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp_lib/draft/draft/test_out_backtrace.cpp:14:23: error: ‘st’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘std’?
   14 |     cout << to_string(st);
      |                       ^~
      |   

I'm sure /usr/include/c++/13/stacktrace exist, how to fix this err

I can't replicate it. My test uses GCC version 12.1, but I tested all the way up to version 13.2. How did you install GCC version 13?

I find the reason,
I install gcc with apt install gcc-13, this gcc doesn't compile stacktrace module, when build gcc, it should build with --enable-libstdcxx-backtrace=yes to include stacktrace
But build and use my compiled gcc make issue complex, so I use boost stacktrace instead std::stracktrace
